# How can you manipulate an element in an inline SVG map with CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

my question is the following: how can I manipulate a map that is made with SVG via CSS? My Problem is that I have different rooms inside of a floor plan of a building.
Now I want the filling of the map to appear when hovering over the inside of the floor plan, but its only doing it when hovering over the stroke, is there a way to change that?

Here is the html file with the inline SVG:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>



    <svg width="857" height="226" viewBox="0 0 857 226" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="Comp-with-rooms-1">
            <g id="8-BIT">
                <text id="8-BIT_2" transform="translate(66.741 200.271) rotate(-90)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">8-BIT&#10;</tspan>
                </text>
                <rect id="8-BIT_3" x="58" y="153" width="32" height="62" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
            </g>
            <g id="ADA">
                <text id="ADA_2" transform="translate(205.741 75.4633)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">ADA&#10;</tspan>
                </text>
                <path id="ADA_3" d="M201 96V74.9227L233 63.8116V96H201Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
            </g>
            <g id="ECHO">
                <path id="ECHO_2" d="M347 62V24.4178L372.127 15.6012L382.5 54.2636V62H347Z" stroke="black"
                    stroke-width="4" />
                <text id="ECHO_3" transform="translate(348.741 45.4633)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">ECHO&#10;</tspan>
                </text>
            </g>
            <g id="ZUSE">
                <path id="ZUSE_2" d="M242 97V60.9274L286 45.8024V97H242Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
                <text id="ZUSE_3" transform="translate(248.741 69.4633)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">ZUSE</tspan>
                </text>
            </g>
            <g id="WARP">
                <text id="WARP_2" transform="translate(299 43)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">WARP&#10;</tspan>
                </text>
                <path id="WARP_3" d="M295 62V42.4515L337 28.7558V62H295Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
            </g>
            <g id="WC">
                <text id="WC_2" transform="translate(788 158)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">WC</tspan>
                </text>
                <rect id="WC_3" x="746" y="113" width="102" height="102" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
            </g>
            <g id="SPOCK">
                <text id="SPOCK_2" transform="translate(680.741 176.463)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">SPOCK&#10;</tspan>
                </text>
                <rect id="SPOCK_3" x="673" y="153" width="56" height="62" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
            </g>
            <g id="ROCK">
                <text id="ROCK_2" transform="translate(152.741 177.463)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">ROCK</tspan>
                </text>
                <rect id="ROCK_3" x="99" y="153" width="139" height="62" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
            </g>
            <g id="PAPER">
                <rect id="PAPER_2" x="247" y="153" width="139" height="62" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
                <text id="PAPER_3" transform="translate(296.741 180.463)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">PAPER</tspan>
                </text>
            </g>
            <g id="LIZARD">
                <text id="LIZARD_2" transform="translate(582.741 180.463)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">LIZARD</tspan>
                </text>
                <rect id="LIZARD_3" x="543" y="153" width="122" height="62" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
            </g>
            <g id="SCISSORS">
                <text id="SCISSORS_2" transform="translate(436.741 177.463)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">SCISSORS&#10;</tspan>
                </text>
                <rect id="SCISSORS_3" x="395" y="153" width="139" height="62" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
            </g>
            <path id="COMPARTMENT_1" d="M856 225V56L542.5 57.5L527.5 13L395 57.5L380.5 1L0.5 132V225H856Z"
                stroke="black" />
        </g>
    </svg>

</body>

</html>
```

With the following CSS, the filling only appears when hovering over the stroke of the elements but I want it to appear when hovering over the Map in general.

Here is my CSS:

```
#COMPARTMENT_1:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3)}
```

Also, is there a way to increase the width and the stroke-width of all the elements when hovering over the map relative to each other so they don't overlap when increasing?

This is my first post here and I am only coding since 2 weeks so please give me feedback if anything is unclear. Thank you already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding hover style to each of your maps like below. Please note if you are using id or class in css the name should not start with numeric value. Here, I changed the name from **8-BIT to BIT**:

```
#BIT rect:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3)}
#ADA path:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3)}
#ECHO path:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3)}
#ZUSE path:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3)}
#WARP path:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3)}
#WC rect:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3)}
#SPOCK rect:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3)}
#ROCK rect:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3)}
#PAPER rect:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3)}
#LIZARD rect:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3)}
#SCISSORS rect:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3)}
```

You can also directly use your path or rect's id and apply css like this :

```
    #BIT_3:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3);
    stroke-width: 8;}
    #ADA_3:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3);
    stroke-width: 8;}
    #ECHO_2:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3);
    stroke-width: 8;}
    #ZUSE_2:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3);
    stroke-width: 8;}
    #WARP_3:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3);
    stroke-width: 8;}
    #WC_3:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3);
    stroke-width: 8;}
    #SPOCK_3:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3);
    stroke-width: 8;}
    #ROCK_3:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3);
    stroke-width: 8;}
    #PAPER_2:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3);
    stroke-width: 8;}
    #LIZARD_3:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3);
    stroke-width: 8;}
    #SCISSORS_3:hover{fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3);
    stroke-width: 8;}
```

And you can add hover effect on its content by adding styles on rect or path like below :

```
.fill-map:hover {
  fill:RGBA(0,200,1,0.3);
   stroke-width: 8;
}

.fill-map {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>



    <svg width="857" height="226" viewBox="0 0 857 226" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="Comp-with-rooms-1">
            <g id="8-BIT">
                <text id="8-BIT_2" transform="translate(66.741 200.271) rotate(-90)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">8-BIT&#10;</tspan>
                </text>
                <rect class="fill-map" id="BIT_3" x="58" y="153" width="32" height="62" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
            </g>
            <g id="ADA">
                <text id="ADA_2" transform="translate(205.741 75.4633)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">ADA&#10;</tspan>
                </text>
                <path class="fill-map" id="ADA_3" d="M201 96V74.9227L233 63.8116V96H201Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
            </g>
            <g id="ECHO">
                <path class="fill-map" id="ECHO_2" d="M347 62V24.4178L372.127 15.6012L382.5 54.2636V62H347Z" stroke="black"
                    stroke-width="4" />
                <text id="ECHO_3" transform="translate(348.741 45.4633)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">ECHO&#10;</tspan>
                </text>
            </g>
            <g id="ZUSE">
                <path class="fill-map" id="ZUSE_2" d="M242 97V60.9274L286 45.8024V97H242Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
                <text id="ZUSE_3" transform="translate(248.741 69.4633)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">ZUSE</tspan>
                </text>
            </g>
            <g id="WARP">
                <text id="WARP_2" transform="translate(299 43)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">WARP&#10;</tspan>
                </text>
                <path class="fill-map" id="WARP_3" d="M295 62V42.4515L337 28.7558V62H295Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
            </g>
            <g id="WC">
                <text id="WC_2" transform="translate(788 158)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">WC</tspan>
                </text>
                <rect class="fill-map" id="WC_3" x="746" y="113" width="102" height="102" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
            </g>
            <g id="SPOCK">
                <text id="SPOCK_2" transform="translate(680.741 176.463)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">SPOCK&#10;</tspan>
                </text>
                <rect class="fill-map" id="SPOCK_3" x="673" y="153" width="56" height="62" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
            </g>
            <g id="ROCK">
                <text id="ROCK_2" transform="translate(152.741 177.463)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">ROCK</tspan>
                </text>
                <rect class="fill-map" id="ROCK_3" x="99" y="153" width="139" height="62" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
            </g>
            <g id="PAPER">
                <rect class="fill-map" id="PAPER_2" x="247" y="153" width="139" height="62" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
                <text id="PAPER_3" transform="translate(296.741 180.463)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">PAPER</tspan>
                </text>
            </g>
            <g id="LIZARD">
                <text id="LIZARD_2" transform="translate(582.741 180.463)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">LIZARD</tspan>
                </text>
                <rect class="fill-map" id="LIZARD_3" x="543" y="153" width="122" height="62" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
            </g>
            <g id="SCISSORS">
                <text id="SCISSORS_2" transform="translate(436.741 177.463)" fill="black" xml:space="preserve"
                    style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">
                    <tspan x="0" y="11.1016">SCISSORS&#10;</tspan>
                </text>
                <rect class="fill-map" id="SCISSORS_3" x="395" y="153" width="139" height="62" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
            </g>
            <path id="COMPARTMENT_1" d="M856 225V56L542.5 57.5L527.5 13L395 57.5L380.5 1L0.5 132V225H856Z"
                stroke="black" />
        </g>
    </svg>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you also know how the filling appears inside the element when not hovering over the stroke but only the inside of the map? Because the hover only works when hovering over the stroke and not the content

Comment: @JulianRoma you should be able to fix that via the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events) property.